# C++ libcurl sending malformed data

Tags: c++, json, libcurl

I am trying to send data to a Apache which is running on localhost. The data is formed correctly in json format, but when I send the data using libcurl and on the PHP webserver I echoed out the string using

```
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
```

It return random characters, this is the data that the server echoed out

```
`é    ²²²²▌▌▌▌4Ég\▌ îHGáF
```

and in C++ when I echo out the json, it prints correctly.

Request.C++

```
void Request::execute() {
auto curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, mUrl);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "RoBot/ Version 1");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &mResponse);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, &mHeaders);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &mResponseCode);

    if (!mData.empty()) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, mData);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, mData.size());
    }

    if (mHeadersData) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, mHeadersData);
    }

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(mHeadersData);
    curl = nullptr;
}
```

And this is how I am executing it.

```
json data;
data["username"] = username;
data["password"] = password;
std::cout << data.dump() << std::endl;

Request* request = new Request("http://localhost:8080/Projects/");
request->setPostData(data.dump());
//request->addHeader("Content-Type: application/json");
request->execute();

std::cout << request->getResponse() << std::endl;
std::cout << request->getHeaders() << std::endl;
```

This is what get printed to the console

```
Username: id
Password: kf
{"password":"kf","username":"id"}
`é    ²²²²▌▌▌▌4Ég\▌ îHGáF
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 27 Aug 2016 09:15:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Win32) PHP/5.4.17
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.17
Content-Length: 36
Content-Type: text/html
```

Any ideas why?

[EDITED]

The write function is showed below

```
size_t write(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string* data) {
data->append((char*)ptr, size * nmemb);
return size * nmemb;
}
```

I am setting the data doing as follow

```
void Request::setPostData(std::string data) {
mData = data;
}
```

[EDITED 2]

So I now know the problem, apparently libcurl only accept char* and I am sending std::string. Is there some sort of way around this since my json library convert a json object to std::string?

Comment: It looks to me that you have an unterminated C-style string. Please show us the `setPostData` and the `write` functions.

Comment: This is missing quite a few bits of infomation. What is `write()` (because libc `write()` has quite a different signature than curl's write function)? What is `mData`? `curl_easy_setopt()` is a varargs function, so type conversion seems mandatory.

Comment: Okay, I updated it with more information as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, mData);
```

Per the libcurl documentation:

[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS explained](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html)

> **Pass a char * as parameter**, pointing to the full data to send in a HTTP POST operation. You must make sure that the data is formatted the way you want the server to receive it. libcurl will not convert or encode it for you in any way. For example, the web server may assume that this data is url-encoded.
>
> **The data pointed to is NOT copied by the library: as a consequence, it must be preserved by the calling application until the associated transfer finishes**. This behaviour can be changed (so libcurl does copy the data) by setting the `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` option.

You are relying on the internal implementation of `std::string` to begin with a `char*` pointer to the character data, but that is not guaranteed. The line should look like this instead:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, mData.c_str());
```

That guarantees you get a `char*` pointer to the character data. The pointer will remain valid until the `std::string` is modified or destroyed.

Comment: Wow I swear I tried that and it didn't work. Apparently it worked now. Thanks alot.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try setting the following request headers?

Accept: text/plain
Accept-Charset: utf-8
Accept-Encoding: [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression#Content-Encoding_tokens)

(perhaps Content-type as well to make sure the server interprets what you send the right way)

[ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields)

Comment: These headers may be revelant if the web server passes back the response in utf16 and/or compressed  and the client library provides it in raw. I wasn't suggesting it is a solution, just a mean to make sure the best effort is done to avoid encoding mismatch between expected/actual (see that "Maybe try..."?)

Comment: @DanielStenberg At the moment I posted my suggestion, the two clarifications regarding the write function and the m_data weren't available (and it was bed time for me). Why a chose to post it as an answer rather than a comment - limited text formatting capabilities in comments.

Comment: @Ahmad Sorry, I only advanced a hypothesis, I wasn't sure what I proposed is categorically true. therefore the "Maybe try to do something" instead of "Maybe you must" and "Perhaps Content-type".